# java file write create empty file in windows only

Tags: java, windows, filewriter, is-empty

I created a code to write information in a file.
So I managed javar through clean and build.
When I run the program in linux the file is generated normally.
However in windows the file is created, but empty.
Does anyone have any ideas?

The code for the button action:

```
private void jToggleButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                               
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
    chooser.setCurrentDirectory(new File(""));
    int retrival = chooser.showSaveDialog(null);
    if (retrival == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        try {
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(chooser.getSelectedFile() + ".txt");
            String result = "";
            String n = nome.getText();
            double c = Double.valueOf(ce.getText());
            double p = Double.valueOf(pd.getText());
            double a = Double.valueOf(ac.getText());
            double notaf = Double.valueOf(nf.getText());
            String s = sit.getText();                
            result = saida(n, c, p, a, notaf, s);
            fw.write(result);
            fw.flush();
            fw.close();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The code for `saida()` function

```
public String saida(String nome, double ce, double pd, double ac, double nf, String sit) {
    StringBuffer sf = new StringBuffer();
    sf.append("Resultado em txt\n");
    sf.append("Nome: "+nome+"\n");
    sf.append("Conhecimentos Específicos: "+ce+"\n");
    sf.append("Prova didática: "+pd+"\n");
    sf.append("Avaliação Curricular: "+ac+"\n");
    sf.append("Nota Final: "+nf+"\n");
    sf.append("Situação: "+sit+"\n");
    sf.append("\n\nResultado em tab\n");
    sf.append("Nome\tConhecimentos Específicos\tProva didática\tAvaliação Curricular\tNota Final\tSituação\n");
    sf.append(nome+"\t"+ce+"\t"+pd+"\t"+ac+"\t"+nf+"\t"+sit);
    sf.append("\n\nPesos\n");
    sf.append("Conhecimentos Específicos: "+p_CE.getText()+"\n");
    sf.append("Prova didática: "+p_PD.getText()+"\n");
    sf.append("Avaliação Curricular: "+p_AC.getText()+"\n");
    return sf.toString();
}
```

Comment: What does the function `saida()` do?

Comment: If you have a problem writing to a file resulting in a IOEX, the file writer will not be closed correctly.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  You've provide an example that's not quite complete or minimal.  Please read about how to post a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  Meanwhile, consider using Java's [try with resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) to avoid the pitfall @lexicore mentions.

Comment: The function saida() concatenates the values of n, c, p, a, notaf, s and returns a string

Comment: The code works fine on Debian and Ubuntu. But in windows 7 its just create the file empty.

Comment: Do yourself a favor, and print out/log result before writing to a file to ensure that is working the same way across all system.  Also, if you are working with Java 7+ do a quick Google search on try-with-resources or even how to properly close a stream (hint: a finally block if you are pre Java-7)

Comment: Thank you so much guys, mainly wrestang.
I found the problem.

I used this line to format the "nota", in other part that I had forgot:
nf.setText(String.format("%.2f", nota));

But when a Run in my Brazilian windows it puts "," intead of ".",
so when the code gets here:
double notaf = Double.valueOf(nf.getText());
it crashes!

So I fix it using this:
double notaf = Double.valueOf(nf.getText());
That is just fine to me.

Thanks a lot for the help.
Now everything is fine XD